# Command line arguments in F# program?

Tags: .net, f#

How can I get command line arguments in F#  compiled program? Is it possible if I don't use default template with

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let Main(args) = ...
```

I've tried

`let args = Sys.argv`

and

`let args = fsi.CommandLineArgs`

but it doesn't work for me :-(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't want to use the args array passed to your main function then you could use `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` instead. Note this will include the name of the program being run as the first item, unlike the args array given to your main function.

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main(args) =    
    printfn "args: %A" args
    printfn "env.cmdline: %A" <| Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()    
    0
```

Run as `args.exe 1 2 3 4`:

```
args: [|"1"; "2"; "3"; "4"|]
env.cmdline: [|"args.exe"; "1"; "2"; "3"; "4"|]
```